# PHP Replacing element in json

Tags: php, json

I have this code:

With this code i load a local json file and attempt to array_replace, replacing if it exists or adding if it doesn't

```
<?php
// check if all form data are submitted, else output error message
$count = count(explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']));
if ( $count > 0 ) {
    $string = file_get_contents("testconfig.json");
    $json_a = json_decode($string, true);

    $replaced_array = array_replace( $json_a, $_GET );
    $jsondata = json_encode($replaced_array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

    if(file_put_contents('testconfig.json', $jsondata)) echo 'OK';
    else echo 'Unable to save data in "testconfig.json"';
}
else 
{ echo 'Form fields not submitted'; }
?>
```

let's say the existing json is something like this:

```
{
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": "val2"
}
```

`status.php?myserver[state]=10`
and would result in this:

```
{
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": "val2",
    "myserver": {
        "state": 10
    }
}
```

But then i would like to ADD to the `myserver` element like this:
`status.php?myserver[mem]=3` and would ADD to the array if it exists, like this:

```
{
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": "val2",
    "myserver": {
        "state": 10,
        "mem": 3
    }
}
```

But my code replaces the whole `myserver` array..

thanks!

Comment: Think [`array_replace_recursive()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php) may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`array_merge_recursive()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php).

```
<?php

$_GET = [
    'myserver' => [
        'state'=>'10'
    ]
];

$existingJson = '{
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": "val2"
}'; 

$array = json_decode($existingJson, true);

$newArray = array_merge_recursive($array, $_GET);

print_r($newArray);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [key1] => val1
    [key2] => val2
    [myserver] => Array
        (
            [state] => 10
        )

)
```

https://3v4l.org/i1YvC

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$newArray = array_replace_recursive($array, $_GET);`?

Comment: Also works for OP's question where `myserver` already exists https://3v4l.org/9G85g